# If Y is a complete metrizable dense subset of a topological Hausdorff space X...

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

If $Y$ is a complete metrizable dense subset of a topological Hausdorff space $X$...then is $X$ a normal space?

I tried to solve it using the fact that every point $x$ in a closed in a Hausdorff space is a limit of a sequence of points in the space. In particular, $Y$ is dense, so there must be a sequence of points of $Y$ converging to $x$. And since $Y$ is completely metrizable, we should have that the point belongs to $Y$. But this seems wrong to me since Y=X, if this is true. Even so, it seems to me that such a fact is true...could someone give me a proof of such a fact or a counterexample?

Comment: You have done nothing that demonstrates normality

Comment: If by "complete metrizable" you mean "completely metrizable" (i.e. homeomorphic to a complete metric space), then in the [half-disc topology](https://topology.jdabbs.com/spaces/S000070/properties) the open half-plane is dense and completely metrizable. However the space is not normal.

Comment: You explicitly need to show that for all closed sets $A,B$ with $A\cap B=\emptyset$, there exist open sets $U,V$ with $A\subseteq U$ and $B\subseteq V$ such that $U\cap V=\emptyset$. As Sassatelli points out, there are counterexamples to this claim in your context.

Comment: @SassatelliGiuliol Another counter-example is the Niemitzky-plane topology on $\Bbb R\times [0,\infty),$ a.k.a. the Moore plane. The dense separable  subspace $Y=\Bbb R\times \Bbb R^+$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$. But $\Bbb R\times\{0\}$ is a closed discrete subspace of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ so by the Jones Lemma, the Niemitzky plane is not normal.